# US bank offering Euro-based card?

Tags: united-states, eur-euro

I'm looking to open an EUR account within the US that offers a Maestro card (in Holland it's called "Betaalpas" which is the only type of card that you can use in all Dutch shops, and with which you can withdraw money without extra cost; also works across the EU). And it should have minimal cost to transfer Euro from a Dutch bank to it.

Comment: Look for a transnational bank.

Comment: Give me an example.

Comment: Product/service recommendations are off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: Nope, there are tons of questions asking for similar things, e.g. http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5102

Comment: @Gabor That doesn't make this one on-topic. You just pointed out other questions that should be closed also per the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an associated Dutch billing address, you can't really use a PIN pass for anything other than point of sale transactions.  Many (most?) online shops in the Netherlands can't deal with any kind of foreign payment, even from neighboring EU countries.  Your best bet in this situation is to maintain a Dutch bank account which gives you the Maestro PIN pass and use cheap transfer services like US Forex, XE Trade or Transferwise to send money to it. This is what I do.

Comment: Thanks, just a small correction that you don't need a Dutch billing address but you do need to have a local "giro" account so my idea of moving my Euro account back to the US is not going to work.

Comment: @Gabor I'm not sure if you've tried, but I have seen forms that only accept Ditch billing/shipping addresses.